# Set CSS design for day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Is it possible to set a specific CSS design for a website for a day?

Say I want the design to change automatically on weekends and normal during days?

I havent worked on classic asp for a while now but I know classic aso has function within tags, so there was a possibility but what about normal HTML page or in asp net ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks guys! great answers. I like the javascript approach better since it can be used with any web language(ASP.net, C#,VB.net etc)

Comment: you can swap the css file with javascript

Comment: http://supergeekery.com/geekblog/comments/change_your_css_styles_based_on_the_day_with_expression_engine hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in comments, its likely your best option is to use javascript as per [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/different-stylesheet-pending-the-time-of-day/)

```
function getStylesheet() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
      if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='morning.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='day.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='evening.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
}

getStylesheet();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know ASP, but you tagged JavaScript, so I'm assuming you're also up to doing this client side. (And it's also probably a good idea, since you'll be using the *client's time*, and not your server's)

**Here's what I'd do:**

```
function loadStyleSheet(url) {
    var styleSheet = document.createElement('link');
    styleSheet.href = url;
    styleSheet.type = 'text/css';
    styleSheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleSheet);
}

var today = new Date().getDay();

if (today === 6 || today === 0) {
    loadStyleSheet('/style/weekendSheet.css');
} else {
    loadStyleSheet('/style/weekdaySheet.css');
}
```

Notice that `getDay` **returns the day as a number**, so you can further expand the script if you want to get more specific.

You should also have a 'default' stylesheet, though, for those users that have JavaScript disabled, and just override the default styles with the appended style sheet.

Comment: Thanks. I like your answer too +1.